# Why does my code do this? line breaks in the middle of every opening tag

Tags: wordpress, view-source

Midwestsalt.net > view source it looks like this throughout the whole site. makes no sense Its hard to debug with these line breaks in everywhere!I am not sure why this happens. SO says to add more details, this is the most i know about what is wrong.
see the php is fine here, the source code renders all crazy and i cant debug it.

```
    <?php
    /**
     * The Header for our theme.
     *
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage MidwestSalt
      */
    ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
    <html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
    <?php /*?><meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" /><?php */?>
    <meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html; charset="utf-8"/> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>
    <?php   /*   * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.  */ global $page, $paged;   wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); // Add the blog name.   bloginfo( 'name' ); //     Add the blog description for the home/front page.        $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );   if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )        echo     " | $site_description";    // Add a page number if necessary:  if (     $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );  ?>
    </title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php     bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
    <link rel="icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php     bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php
    /* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
     * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>
    <?php 
    global $post; 
    global $curr_cat;
    global $wpdb;
    global $product_categories;
    global $maincatname;
    $curr_cat = get_current_category();

    $maincatname = get_viewmode();
    if (!$maincatname)
    $maincatname = 'homeowners';

    $maincat = get_category_by_name($maincatname);
    $where_maincat = ' AND parent = '.$maincat->term_id;                

    $product_categories = $wpdb->get_results("
                        SELECT *,
                        (SELECT meta_value     FROM wp_wpsc_meta WHERE object_type = 'wpsc_category' AND meta_key = 'image' AND object_id = term_id) AS image
                        FROM wp_terms 
                        WHERE term_id IN     (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'wpsc_product_category' $where_maincat)
                        AND term_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM wp_wpsc_meta WHERE object_type = 'wpsc_category' AND meta_key = 'active' AND meta_value = '1')
                        ");
?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php     bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/prettyPhoto.css"     media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php     bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js">    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/fadeSlideShow-minified.js">    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/allscripts.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body class="<?php if ($post->ID == 2 || $post->ID == 136 || $post->ID == 139) echo 'landing'; elseif($curr_cat) echo 'product-listing'; elseif($post->post_type=='post') echo 'blog-view'; elseif(is_category()) echo 'blog-listing'; else echo 'catalog-product-view';?> <?php echo $maincatname; ?>">

    <noscript>
    <div class="noscript">
        <div class="noscript-inner">
            <p><strong>We detected that your JavaScript seem to be disabled.</strong></p>
            <p>You must have JavaScript enabled in your browser to utilize the functionality of this website.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </noscript>

    <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="main-header-wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"     class="logo"><strong><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?> - <?php bloginfo(     'description' ); ?></strong></a>
            <div class="header-right">
                <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li id="nav-home"><a href="<?php echo     get_option('home');?>"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
                    <li id="nav-about">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_option('home');?>/about-us"><strong>About us</strong></a>
                        <?php 
                            $items = get_block_items('show_in_header','Yes'); 
                            if ($items): ?>
                            <ul     class="dropdown">
                            <?php     foreach($items as $item): ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($item->ID)?>"><?php echo $item->post_title?></a></li>
                            <?php     endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav-products">
                        <a href="<?php product_page_link(); ?>"><strong>Products</strong></a>
                        <ul class="product-dropdown">
                            <?php foreach($product_categories as $item): ?>
                            <?php if     ($item->slug == 'product-category') continue; ?>
                            <li><a     href="<?php product_page_link(); ?><?php echo $item->slug;?>"><img     width="136" height="85" alt="" src="<?php echo ne_image_resize(get_option('home').'/wp-content/uploads/wpsc/category_images/'.$item->image,136,85,'category_images'); ?>" /><span><?php echo strtoupper($item->name)?></span></a></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav-contact"><a href="<?php echo get_option('home');?>/contact-us"><strong>Contact us</strong></a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="<?php echo get_option('home');?>" class="btn-chat"><strong>Live chat - click here</strong></a>
                <?php language_selector_form(); ?>
                <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                <ul class="user-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li>|</li>
                    <li><a href="#">My account</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="block-cart"><span>0</span> items in cart</p>
                <p class="contact-info"><?php _get('header_phone',2); ?> <span><?php _get('header_location',2); ?></span></p>
                <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                <?php /*
                <p class="slogan">WE DO ALL THE HEAVY LIFTING FOR YOU</p>
                */ ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_option('home');?>/refer-a-friend" class="btn-refer"><strong>refer friends</strong></a>
                <?php if ($_link = _get('existing_customers_link',2,true)): ?>
                <?php if ($_image = _get_image('existing_customers_image',2,true)): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_link; ?>" class="btn-existing"><img src="<?php echo $_image; ?>" /><strong>existing customers</strong></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end: header -->
    </div>
    <!-- end: main-header-wrapper -->
```

So any ideas why?

Comment: where is the source code (php)

Comment: w3c says they are errors

Comment: how do i show you the php?